# Automated Unit Testing with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeigniter

Anyone using CodeIgniter use automated unit testing?

Seems the way CodeIgniter's guy do unit test need to have a controller which run in browser,

e.g.

1. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html
2. or this: http://jensroland.com/projects/toast/

However, I only want to test from command line, I want automated test and build.

Any recommendation?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a nice resource with PHPunit.
**Unit testing a real world Codeigniter application** [http://vimeo.com/28588831](http://vimeo.com/28588831)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this integration with phpunit - http://www.foostack.com/foostack/

It would then run from the command line.

Comment: FYI, foostack does not seem to be compatible with CI 2.0 and above.

Comment: Not tested myself, but this project (https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit) is a fork of CIUnit Foostack for CI 2.x.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do:

- Download [Test.php](http://search.cpan.org/~avar/Test.php-0.13/Test.php)
- Create a 't' directory at the root of my CI app
- Put Test.php in the t directory
- Create a bootstrap.php file (see below) to initialize testing
- `require_once` the bootstrap.php file in my tests.
- Run `prove` on tests in the t directory

`bootstrap.php`:

```
<?php

// Initialize CodeIgniter, suppressing output.
ob_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/../index.php';
ob_end_clean();

require_once __DIR__ . '/Test.php';
```

An example of a test:

`t/000-sanity.t`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

plan(1);

is(true, true, 'Test.php works');
```

All CodeIgniter stuff is available. For example, you can do `$ci =& get_instance();`

This setup works great in CI 1.7.x and 2.x. Test.php is really easy to use, as well.

Comment: This does not work (anymore). The output is never suppressed and CodeIgniter exits the PHP process so unfortunately tests never run. Tested with CodeIgniter 2.2.0