# How can I easily unit test with CodeIgniter?

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter, phpunit

I want to test my controllers / models with CodeIgniter. How can I accomplish this with CodeIgniter?

Comment: I dont understand the question... whats the difference running on a mac, you can carry out unit testing through a custom built page on your codeigniter site. CI Unit tests aren't done through cli, even if they were (I'm sure you could if you wanted to) every mac os is sat on top of a unix build

Comment: Modified my question to reflect what I want

Comment: question closed, but for reference, this is really good.  https://packagist.org/packages/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check out unit testing here:
[unit testing with CI](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html)

This might help too: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883333/automated-unit-testing-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 3):

The platform you're using is irrelevant. You can use the built-in CodeIgniter [Unit testing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/unit_testing.html) library, or if you would like an approach which is more similar to many common Unit testing libraries, I'd suggest you to use Toast:
http://jensroland.com/projects/toast/

Comment: Thanks! Here is a nice resource with PHPunit and a real Codeigniter application. http://vimeo.com/28588831